# Parsing SOAP XML response with XMLTABLE in DB2

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to get ResponseMSG into the table by using XMLTABLE and there is something wrong with PATH when I'm parsing SAOP response. The error is :
SQL STATE 10506, Code -16005
***XPath expession references undefined name soap witht static context***
I'm not sure what is wrong here. There is no namespace in the XML so I thought that path
***/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendFileResponse/SendFileResult*** is the correct one.

The SQL that I'm using:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM XMLTABLE(
'$doc/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendFileResponse/SendFileResult' PASSING 
XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT systools.HTTPPOSTCLOB('https://someurl.asmx?op=SendFile',
                            '<httpHeader>
                                <header name ="content-type" value ="text/xml"/>
                             </httpHeader>',
                            GET_CLOB_FROM_FILE('/folder/file1.txt')))
as "doc"
COLUMNS
Value VARCHAR(128) PATH '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/SendFileResponse/SendFileResult') as a with all;
```

The response from HTTPPOSTCLOB is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SendFileResponse xmlns="http://e-customs.com/">
            <SendFileResult>A file with the name file1.txt has already been uploaded.</SendFileResult>
        </SendFileResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The file.txt which has an xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendFile xmlns="http://test-url.com/">
      <EM>
        <Security>
          <CompanyName>aaa</CompanyName>
          <UserId>bbb</UserId>
          <CompanyPassword>ccc</CompanyPassword>
          <UserPassword>ddd</UserPassword>
        </Security>
        <Action>atNew</Action>
        <File>
          <Filename>string</Filename>
          <FileSize>12</FileSize>
          <FileContent>some content</FileContent>
          <FileType>ftCDS2Level</FileType>
          <ExtraInfo1>string</ExtraInfo1>
          <ExtraInfo2>string</ExtraInfo2>
          <ExtraInfo3>string</ExtraInfo3>
          <ExtraInfo4>string</ExtraInfo4>
          <ExtSysId>string</ExtSysId>
        </File>
      </EM>
    </SendFile>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: The Web service response has a default namespace: `xmlns="http://e-customs.com/"`. You need to take it into account for both **SendFileResponse** as well as **SendFileResult** elements,

Comment: I've tried with PATH '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*:SendFileResponse/*:SendFileResult and it still did not work or I can't use '*:' in that case?

Comment: I've added 
```xmlnamespaces ('http://e-customs.com/' as "ec")``` to xmltable   and modified PATH to:
```PATH '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ec:SendFileResponse/ec:SendFileResult'```
and I still get the same error

Comment: Please edit your question, and add your `SELECT ...` statement from the XML response in question.

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding rest of the namespaces. I will post correct SQL in original post.

Comment: Good to hear.  

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding rest of the namespaces in the SELECT...

```
SELECT a.*
FROM XMLTABLE( xmlnamespaces ('http://e-customs.com/' as "ec",
    'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' as "soap",
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi",
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd"),
'$doc/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ec:SendFileResponse/ec:SendFileResult' PASSING 
XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT systools.HTTPPOSTCLOB('https://uat.e-customs.descartes.com/webservices/ecustomsexchange.asmx?op=SendFile',
                            '<httpHeader>
                                <header name ="content-type" value ="text/xml"/>
                             </httpHeader>',
                            GET_CLOB_FROM_FILE('/General/emcsandnesfilesftp/new1.txt')))
as "doc"
COLUMNS
Value VARCHAR(128) PATH '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ec:SendFileResponse/ec:SendFileResult') as a with all;
```

Now it returns what I need.